# search canadian province

Tags: php, mysql

I have an input search on the site and I want to search in the database (MySQL) after province name.

In database I have just the provinces initials - ex: QC for Quebec, AB - Alberta, etc.

The people can introduce into the input search field: QC or PC or Province du Québec or Province Quebec or Quebec or Québec (capital letters or not) (of course - this is just for one of the province, but are more :) )

What kind of SQL statment I can use or how can I solve my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an alias table where you can define all the synonyms for a given province (ie. alias). Each alias would have a FK to the province it belongs. You can then do your search against the alias table and do a join to your province table to find whatever province.

Comment: Agreed - good approach. nextu, this could get you started on the provinces table: http://vancouverwebconsultants.com/mysql-table-for-canadian-provinces-with-iso-code/ . The alias table would be something like id, alias, prov_id. All the best.